# Command-line tool to dump all Device Properties displayed in Device Manager

Tags: windows, drivers, device

In Device Manager, clicking on a specific device takes you to a dialog box, whose Details tab shows all sorts of properties of the device. Is there a command line tool to dump this out? I need to diff all the properties of two devices.

Comment: did you figure out the answer ?

Answer (score 9):

It seems to me that `msinfo32` puts out all the information you could want including ports, IRQs, and addresses used.

try: `msinfo32 /report msiout.txt`

Note that the command prompt returns immediately, but `msinfo` runs in the background.  You need to wait for the file to show up.

Comment: `start /w msinfo32.exe /report msiout.txt` causes the command prompt to wait until the file is generated.

Answer (score 5):

msinfo32 has a number of [command line switches](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300887) you can use to dump the output to a file

Comment: This is a good tip, thanks. Unfortunately msinfo32 does not show all device properties.

Answer (score 5):

[Devcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon-status) is one such tool. It is built by Microsoft, and is open source.

For eg. to Check status of all PCI devices on the system, on could use:-

```
devcon status pci*
```

Similarly, to check status of all devices :-

```
devcon status *
```

More information about the tool, and its usage is given in its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon-status).

The source code can be found on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/setup/devcon).

The utility gets installed with Windows SDK, Visual Studio, and WDK; see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon).

On my machine the 64 bit version of the tool is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Tools\x64`

Comment: Is there a way to obtain `devcon` as a standalone utility without installing multigigabytes of Windows SDK, WDK, etc.?  UPDATE: here it is https://superuser.com/questions/1002950/quick-method-to-install-devcon-exe

Comment: hahaha... you're right @evaldaz.... that was crazy.

Comment: devcon is much faster than msinfo32, and it was perfect for my purpose (I needed to spot what device was causing Windows to bleep every 30 seconds like in a connection/disconnection of a device, and I needed the dump to be very quick). Thanks also @evaldaz for posting the link to the SuperUser question on how to get devcon with a small download

Answer (score 0):

Get everything seen in Device Manager, Device Properties Details tab via PowerShell:
`Get-PnpDevice -InstanceId "USB\VID_0979*" | Get-PnpDeviceProperty | Export-Csv DevDetails.csv`

[I guess Microsoft doesn't recommend using `devcon.exe` anymore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon-migration) suggesting to use `pnputil.exe` which is built-in :) [pnputil examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil-examples)